# no such column: users_profile.user_id - Django

Tags: python, django

I have created an app in my Django project called users, and I have created a model called Profile. After registering the app in the admin panel also install the app in the **settings.py** and created the view for it. When I click on the profile inside the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/user/Profile` I get the following error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/users/profile/
no such column: users_profile.user_id
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/users/profile/
Django Version: 3.2.6
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such column: users_profile.user_id
Exception Location: C:\Users\Serage\Desktop\devsearch\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 423, in execute
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Serage\Desktop\devsearch\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Serage\\Desktop\\devsearch',
 'c:\\users\\serage\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python39.zip',
 'c:\\users\\serage\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\DLLs',
 'c:\\users\\serage\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib',
 'c:\\users\\serage\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39',
 'C:\\Users\\Serage\\Desktop\\devsearch\\env',
 'C:\\Users\\Serage\\Desktop\\devsearch\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 18 Sep 2021 13:59:55 +0000
```

My profile code is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import uuid
# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    short_intro = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)>
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(null = True, blank = True, upload_to='profiles/', default="profiles/user-default.png")
    social_github = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    social_github = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    social_linkedIn = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    social_youtube = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    social_website = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)
```

Please assist

Comment: Have you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: I did many times and everything sounds OK, but when I click on Profile in my admin I get the error

Comment: What about `python manage.py showmigrations` it gives you that you have all migrations applied?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to delete all your migration files in the Web App,
Then run `python manage.py makemigrations` & `python manage.py migrate` cmds

***if still the problem remains***

drop your Database and repeat the upper steps.

Hope theese will works for you.

Comment: I do delete all files in migrations folder, and re-run makemigrations and migrate and it goes through but when I go to my 8000/admin/users/profile I get the same error

Comment: Hello @Serage try to run this command ```python manage.py makemigrations users```

Comment: It was a glitch in Django, I updated  a model in another app and run migrations and it is working fine now 

Comment: @Serage Glad to hear that :)